# Checkmate with 3 bishops vs 1 bishop

Tags: endgame, checkmate, bishops, kings

I know that you can mate with two bishops, but I do not know whether it is possible if White has 3 bishops, and Black has 1 bishop. Is there a general method? If so, is it possible for White to checkmate in all cases, where he has *n+2* bishops and Black has *n* bishops?

Comment: trade the one bishop :P

Comment: But is it possible to force Black to trade it?

Comment: Ask EGTB :P (15chrs)

Comment: If superior side has 2 light squared bishops and a dark-squared bishop and the inferior side has a dark squared bishop, I would not be surprised if it is a draw as you cannot mate with two bishops of the same square color.

Comment: The endgame tablebases seem to consistently give the win to White if White has exactly 2 bishops of the same square color as Black's bishop, and a draw otherwise. The strategy seems to be to bring the king to action and push Black's king to the edge. Black's bishop does not seem to be able to stop the attacks, and many lines seem to just ignore it instead of trading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

White must have two bishops of one colour and a bishop of the other to get checkmate. White can then attempt to pin Black's lone bishop, which is. easier as more pieces get on the board. Then, White can checkmate.